# Android Drawable Horizontal Line

Tags: android, xml-drawable

Is it possible to make line to be like this with xml? or there's some way to do that..?

[image]

I already made some drawable with shape but it's not really like i want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0.8dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create a drawable file also for this. May be helpful for someone.

**Drawable file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="25dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**Result :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#de0b0b" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

USE like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:text="Nilesh"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

### EDIT

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#a032e4" />
            <solid android:color="#a032e4" />
            <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="4dp" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

> USE LIKE THIS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @RizkyNofriwandi so why dont you just use `NinePatchDrawable`?

Comment: in real device you will see a thin line with white color even you give background with white color

Comment: @pskink can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: @RizkyNofriwandi did you see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925377/android-drawable-horizontal-line#comment90801534_51925377) above?

Comment: @pskink yes i already read it but where i have to search it? in my project already have it or how? i'm sorry i'm so confuse about ninepatchdrawable

Comment: @RizkyNofriwandi `"so find textfield_default_holo_light.9.png in your sdk "` you dont have android sdk installed?

Comment: @pskink i already find it but it's just image file PNG right? so what i have to do is read the documentations in developer android?

Comment: @Subzero just because i rejected you edit that not mean the solution is ugly

Comment: @Subzero also the answer is about `drawable` not about layout

Comment: why dont you simply check how standard `EditText` handles its own background?

Comment: @pskink didn't get it sir/

Comment: @pskink means i didn't understand this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925377/android-drawable-horizontal-line/51925626?noredirect=1#comment90811160_51925626

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925377/android-drawable-horizontal-line/51925626?noredirect=1#comment90800519_51925377

Comment: here you have [et.9.png](https://pasteboard.co/HA9z7r5.png), place it in `drawable-xxhdpi` folder and just use `android:background="@drawable/et"` in layout xml file

Comment: @pskink its working perfectly Please post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:insetLeft="-5dp"
            android:insetRight="-5dp"
            android:insetTop="-10dp">

       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
           <stroke
             android:width="3dp"
             android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
       <corners
          android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
          android:bottomRightRadius="25dp" />
       </shape>
     </inset>
```