# Edit Box with small tip at both ends

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am looking to design an edit box to look as following - as small tip at both ends

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated!.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use a third party library called MaterialEditText

Comment: Check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925377/android-drawable-horizontal-line/51925626#comment90833966_51925626

Comment: create an xml file which has this kind of a design and set that file as background in your edittext.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below drawable xml in your textview or editText background:-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FF500778" />

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    </shape>
</item>
 </layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Nainal!

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable file like below and set it as background for your edit text

**Drawable file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**Result:**

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Thanks for the help @Santosh! Stack overflow does not allow to accept multiple answers. So I am up voting your answer

Comment: Whenever you get a confusion, use [First Come First Served](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/first-come-first-served) method.. Just Kidding ;)

Answer (score 1):

make a xml file in your drawable folder with this codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#de0b0b" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="10dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

for usage, use

```
android:background="@drawable/name"
```

to your textView or EditText

I hope this could help you

Comment: Thanks for the help @Milad! Stack overflow does not allow to accept multiple answers. So I am up voting your answer